# ul >li style and keeping it inside one line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu list item which has 4 items but it doesn't feed inside one line for some reason. I tried nested it with nested divs but had no luck. The problem starts to happen when I added the `padding: 10px;`.

Here is the latest HTML and CSS I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I also have a jsfiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/GLh92/1/

As you can see, it doesn't fit inside the one line. I also have a responsiveness concern here. So, it needs to fit inside one line for different screen resolutions.

Any idea how this can be done in a clean way?

Comment: for one, close your anchor tags..

Comment: @McMastermind that was a typo mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on the `li` elements.  This will make the padding part of the width calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GLh92/5/

Comment: What about this case?

http://jsfiddle.net/GLh92/365/

Any way to stay on the same line?

Answer (score 4):

Look into the box-sizing css property, it will change your life.

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the padding to the `<a>` tags, instead of the `<li>` tags since padding adds to the actual width.

1. Remove padding from `<li>`
2. Add `padding: 10px;` to `<a>`
3. Close your `<a>` tags

http://jsfiddle.net/GLh92/7/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: gray;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding adds width and/or height to your elements, you should handle padding or margin with the children of your li elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention `padding:10px;` its also increases the width of the `<li>` item. So you need to take care of `width:20%;`

Try this:

```
#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding:10px;
}
```

It will comes under the same line. Is this what are you looking for ?

Comment: @Axel also having different solution for ur prob.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the width to 25%  to each of the li element.
You have four list elements, its fine as long as there is no padding ( 25*4 = 100 ) But when you add padding one of the element moves to to next line.( 25*4 + 10(padding) > 100 )

change the value of width to something else line 15%

```
#menu li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
width: 15%;
background-color: gray;
padding: 10px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/GLh92/9/

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution. I wanted to fill the line completely with 4 items and I also wanted to make it responsive against different screen resolutions. See the accepted answer.